# How can I create a PyQt5 UI that can be modified using a terminal that runs as a subprocess

Tags: python, terminal, pyqt

I want to create a PyQt5 program that has the following:
A basic window:

```
app = QApplication([])  
root = QMainWindow()  
root.show()  
app.exec_()
```

A terminal that runs a user input and can accept commands such as *root.setWindowTitle("PyQt")*
or if it were in a class *className.setWindowTitle("PyQt")*.
This terminal must be the one from where you started running the program (xterm, terminus, gnome-terminal ...).

Final note, I have tried the QThread, multiprocess, threading, subprocess libraries to no avail.

Comment: "I want to create a PyQt5 program that has..." Ok, so? What have you tried? Have you got something already? Is there a problem in the code you've written until now?

Comment: @musicamante Yep. I created a subprocess which worked nicely. Unfortunately, any command which I ran inside this process would not affect the main GUI and if I passed anything back to the main process for running it there, the GUI would hung up.

Comment: It might help to break this problem into two separate problems, the first problem being getting any Python script to accept input from the terminal and "executing" the input strings against object instances in your script.

Comment: @101 I did manage to make it with the exception of being able to cause the commands inputted to make a change in the UI

Comment: So you already have access to user input strings within your PyQt app, and you just need to _execute_ them?

Comment: @101 I can execute them inside the thread but nothing in the UI is affected and if I execute it in the UI (main thread) it freezes up.